# how to stop logged user deleting own accont

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have no idea in how to do this but I want to stop a user that is logged in from deleting their user

In my user_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_url
end
```

in my user/index.html.erb I have

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Link to If helper

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if

```
<%= link_to_if(current_user != user,'Delete', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete )%>
```

Comment: Hello @AndreyDeineko , **It will generate link to delete any user if and only if it's not same user who logged in.**

Comment: not the current user, but user in general - read the question carefully

Comment: Hello @AndreyDeineko , Please read **how to stop logged user deleting own accont** -  main title of question

Comment: the title has changed since I've given the answer, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko How so?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
link_to_unless
```

will be more verbose.

I've encountered some troubles with link_to_if. You may use:

```
<% unless @current_user == user %>
   #your link
<% end %>
```